# annotations not working when migrating to java 11

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, java-11

Is there anything i can do to get the @Mock and @InjectMocks annotation to work with java 11?

Comment: One thing you could try is to mock `locale` as well and leave the object creation to `mockito` instead of initializing it yourself.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. `final` mocking is only possible with mockito version > `2.1`. If you can't update, you might need to use `PowerMockito` for this. Or you have to explain in more detail what the `java7` problem is and why you can't simple move it into the `setUp` method.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core. After the update check the current [documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) as well, on how to enable `final` mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this worked for you in Java7, but you clearly use `@InjectMocks` in a wrong way.

```
@InjectMocks
private ByVehicleIdRequest request = new ByVehicleIdRequest(
   locale,
   additionalInfo,
   permissions,
   switches,
   vehicleId, 
   aftermarketDescriptions, 
   enhancedStringMatchingSettings);
```

If you use Mockito runner (or extension in JUnit5), you should not initialize the field yourself:

```
@InjectMocks
private ByVehicleIdRequest request;
```

As described in [MockitoJUnitRunner documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html):

> Mocks are initialized before each test method.

If you use the mock values in the field initialization of `request` object, you are passing not-yet-initialized values to the constructor, and hence null values you observe.

**Note**

The answer refers to question version 3.

Comment: Then create your instance of ByVehicleIdRequest yourself, but not in a field initialized, but in `@Before` (jUnit4) / `@BeforeEach` (jUnit5) method

Comment: Both "Too much code is run" or "the test fails" are not specific enough. We cannot see the work you do in the constructor (usual tasks like initializing fields do not cause any errors when repeated), nor can we guess what error you observe.

Comment: It is not initialized properly because you dont pass it to the constructor of request `request = new ByVehicleIdRequest(locale, additionalInfo, permissions, switches, vehicleId, aftermarketDescriptions,
        enhancedStringMatchingSettings);` but clearly it is one of its fields (screenshot). Are you mixing constructor and setter injection in your code? If so, you need also to call appropriate setters.